# Use moveTaskToBack in OnBackPressed, still destroy Activity

Tags: android

I have already searched through stackoverflow site, but unfortunately all answers are not working for me.
For some reasons, I want activity not being destroyed when users press Back button to back home screen if background service is still running.

App normal workflow like:
**startup screen->main activity**

1. when pressed back button, and then reopen app, workflow like:
   **startup screen->main activity, activity's state not like before back home screen(that is not what I want)**
2. when pressed home button, and then reopen app, workflow like:
   **main activity, activity's state like before back home screen(that is what I want)**

Any idea how to get 2? I know at 2, activity not being destroyed, just being paused or stopped, but how override back button and let it act like pressing home button?

Follow someone's ideas, using moveTaskToBack in onBackPressed, workflow is still like 1.

Below are codes I have tried,

```
public class SimpleActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
.....
.....
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (musicPlayService!=null||serviceBinder)
            unbindService(serviceConnection);
        PlaylistFragment.checkBoxFlag=false;
        unregisterReceiver(detectHeadset);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove **super.onBackPressed()**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, and the solution you provided is also not working for me, I have tried before I asked.